# TextBox ScrollToCaret causing threading confusion

Tags: winforms, multithreading, events, textbox, richtextbox

Apparently System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.ScrollToCaret can cause additional events to be processed within its call.  When placed within an event handler it can make code appear to run in a multievent (not really multithreaded but just as confusing) fashion causing race conditions.  Apologizing in advance for missing details:

1) Windows form app .NET C# 3.5

2) Create a Canvas and RichTextBox

3) Start a worker thread that calls canvas.Invalidate() at 30fps.

4) Capture OnMouseMove() and Paint() for the canvas.

5) Within OnMouseMove append append text to a RichTextBox and call ScrollToCaret().

6) Use a static short _eventdepth that ++ at top and -- at bottom of each of OnMouseMove  and OnPaint.

7) Trap when the value of _eventdepth > 1.  Stack Trace:

```
   Canvas::OnPaint()
   [External Code] 
   Canvas::OnMouseMove(),  scrollToCaret() is within
```

Is this behavior documented and supposed to work like this--are there are "GUI" calls that will distribute "child" events?  Sharing this in case some one else starts burning time on it or in case I am misunderstanding whats happening.

--- edit ---

I have also now wrapped the call to canvas.Invalidate (step 3) from the secondary thread with BeginInvoke.  I also had a lock that was blocking when that happens windows begins to dispatch additional events (in the same primary thread) as a solution rather than block (and hang like I would have expected).

The ScrollToCaret() still causes OnPaint() to be called from within the same stack.  Is it just obvious to to windows programmers which methods may trigger additional event dispatches?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you follow Microsoft's recommendation to manipulate the control, it can still give you unexpected high CPU usage and hang (the cause seems to be inside riched20.dll.

So I suggest you use a simple TextBox or switch to WPF completely.